# Rotman's Homological Algebra, Cor 9.80 Induced and Coinduced

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

I have a question about the proof of Cor 9.80 in Rotman's Homological Algebra (2nd Edition).

The proof is as follows:

[image]

His definition of induced and coinduced are

[image]

What I don't get is the proof of the second part ii, so I know that since $G$ is finite, coinduced module $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}G,A)$ is isomorphic to induced module $\mathbb{Z}G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ and so he wants to show that $(\mathbb{Z}G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A)^S$ is $G/S$-induced i.e showing $(\mathbb{Z}G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A)^S \cong \mathbb{Z}(G/S) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ for some abelian group $B$.

But I don't see how showing that $n_{sx} = n_x$ gives us that result.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of seeing what's going on is that there are two inclusions
$$
\phi:(\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)^S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}G,A)
$$
and
$$
\psi:\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}(G/S),A)\rightarrow\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}G,A).
$$
The second inclusion $\psi$ is given by restriction along the quotient $\mathbb{Z}G\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}(G/S)$, and its image can be identified as those functions $f\colon G\rightarrow A$ that are constant on cosets of $S$ in $G$. Rotman's proof of (ii) amounts to saying that the image of the first inclusion $\phi$ consists of the same functions, which shows that $(\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)^S\cong\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}(G/S),A)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it makes sense to me now.